# Access VBA Module cannot get data from Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

OK, so my database was originally designed in Access 2003. On one of the machines I am using a Access 2007 Runtime as the machine does not have Office of any flavor. I am trying to find a solution using the latest version of Access in Office 365.  I cannot directly access either the live version running on either Access 2003 or Access 2007 Runtime. I cannot change the versions on the other machines as these are located in a prison and have no internet. This works without issue running in 2003, only the 2007 is the issue.  As I am not there and only have 365, I need a solution that will work for all versions.

The functions being used are in separate modules and are not on the actual form. The form is set to have module as that is required to access the objects. The function is to add an session for an inmate to attend the library. This must be verified to make sure there is room at the time and day of week selected, as well as individual session limits.

The issue I am dealing with is the 2007 and 365 versions are unable to get the selected data from a list box (time as a string) and option group (DayofWeek as number) to complete a SQL query instead it inserts nothing and the SQL fails claiming there is an extra ) in my code. The SQL is then used to create a DAO recordset. This is part of a verification of data to ensure limits are not reached.

I have triple checked the string sent to CO_GetSessionDetail to ensure I do not have an extra ). It thinks it does as there is nothing on the right side of my = in the string. I checked the reference to the form and the unbound fields and they all match. It compiles no problem.

THERE IS NO ISSUE IN 2003 ...

The code is posted below.

```
Function CO_NewCallout() As Boolean
...
    ' Get Session ID --------------------------------- '
    With Form_f_COs_IM
        iSession = CO_GetSessionDetail( _
            "SessionID", _
            "(((t_CO_Sess.DayOfWeek) = " & .CO_Add_DayOfWeek & ") AND " & _
            "((t_CO_Sess.tSession) = '" & .CO_Add_tSession & "'))" _
            )
        If iSession = 0 Then
            GoTo CO_NewCallout_Exit
        End If
    End With
...
End Function

Function CO_GetSessionDetail(stfield As String, stwhere As String) As Variant
'On Error Resume Next

' Variable Declerations -------------------------- '
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim stSQL As String

' Set Variables ---------------------------------- '
    Set db = CurrentDb
    If stwhere <> "" Then
        stwhere = "WHERE " & stwhere
    End If
    stSQL = _
        "SELECT * " & _
        "FROM t_CO_Sess " & stwhere
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(stSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

' Get Session ID --------------------------------- '
    With rst
        If Not .EOF Then
            CO_GetSessionDetail = .Fields(stfield)
        Else
            CO_GetSessionDetail = 0
        End If
    End With

' Close Recordset t_CO_Sess ---------------------- '
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

Access 2003 - I get the unique ID of the Session

Access 2007 and 365 - cannot complete function

Let me know if more code would help.

Answer (score 0):

An Access application compiled using Office 365 will not be compatible with the Access 2007 runtime or Access 2003. You must compile on a version earlier or equal to the runtime you choose. Unfortunately, it is hard to get the Access 2003 runtime because it is not freely downloadable. The 2007 runtime is freely available (which probably explains why you chose to install the later version).

Your code looks OK, and I assume it compiles and all that. Despite the fact that your 2003 database *should* work with the Access 2007 runtime, the fact that it *doesn't* says to me that you have an incompatibility you need to resolve.

Your best bet: upgrade your app to 2007 or later, ensure it works in the new version, and install the matching runtime on your client's machines.

References:

General discussion of Access version compatibility:
[Access 2016/2010 Compatibility, Access 2016](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2039884)

Article on getting the Access 2003 Runtime:
[MS Access Runtime 2003](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c9a2d779-d1a5-4546-bfc1-fa8cd5758a15/ms-access-runtime-2003?forum=accessdev)

Comment: no I am just testing in 365 ... the update and compile will be done in 2003.  The code works in 2003, the problem is the compiled 2003 working in 2007 runtime.

Comment: You need to either get the 2003 Runtime (hard to get, see second reference), or upgrade your app and all runtimes to 2007 or later.

Comment: Turned out the issue was due to no records in the 365 copy. The issue in 2007 was the    Environ    object, got the workaround, so no more problems. Thx.